# jquery live with zero clipboard

Tags: ajax, jquery, zeroclipboard

I am using Jquery and Zeroclipboard.

I have used $.post for an ajax call, after which the Zero Clipboard events no longer work.

I have tried playing about with $("#id").live..

How can I wrap Zero Clipboard around a live query or implement a solution that keeps the events even after ajax calls?

Function that is called on PHP page to load Zero Clipboard elements:

```
function LiveZeroClipboard(copyText)
{   
var i = clips.length;

clips[i] = Array();
clips[i]['client'] = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
clips[i]['client'].setHandCursor(true);
clips[i]['client'].setText(copyText);

clips[i]['client'].addEventListener('onMouseOver', function(client){
    rollOverCSS(2);
});

clips[i]['client'].addEventListener('onMouseOut', function(client){
    rollOverCSS(1);
});

clips[i]['client'].addEventListener( 'onMouseUp', function(client) {
    //fades in a popup and fades out after 1000 miliseconds
    $('#'+AddressPopupBoxID).fadeIn("fast");
    setTimeout(function(){$('#'+AddressPopupBoxID).fadeOut();},1000);
});
```

}

onClick function that loads Ajax file:

```
function AjaxCall(postURL, JSONData, UpdateID){
$.post (postURL, { data_to_send:JSONData }, function (data_back){
        $(UpdateID).html(data_back);
    })
```

}

So after the ajax file loads onto the webpage, the Zero Clipboard events no longer work.

I am guessing the document scope is now only in the ajax file, which is simply a PHP file that updates a button and triggers some database tasks.

What is the solution to keep the Zero Clipboard events live?

Thanks

Comment: You should post what your javscript currently looks like.

Comment: And html as well, as to see which elements are impacted by your ajax call. For example if the flash element used by Zeroclipboard is no more on the page, that may alter its functions.

Comment: I have edited the post and included the ZeroClipboard events and ajax request.